# Code formatting broke on my answer?

Tags: support, markdown, code, tabs

If you look over at my answer in my revision history you'll see something strange. I did not modify the big code block yet it says I did(though the only thing I apparently "changed" is deleted `>` and replaced it with `>` heh)

see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3534085/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of the original answer, it has tabs; in the revised answer, it has spaces.  There are only three spaces, so the code is not formatted as such.

Comment: Heh, that's strange then that it would flip flop between working and not working with tabs